# Angular - store Token in Local Storage inject

Tags: angular

My question is different than is it secure to store Auth token in `Local Storage`. I'm already decided to do that. And I have `canActivate` method which guards routes that are not meant to be accessible by not logged users. 
I simply check for token - is it present in `Local Storage`. If yes I navigate user to that route.

My problem is what if someone injects token in my Local Storage, just some string to be present - It will automatically have access to the routes? 
I don't have problem with contacting APIs because all of them are Authorized with token and roles. But I have problem that someone can go in all routes that are for registered users.

I think about adding Authorized Api and on every `canActivate` I check that API is token Valid.

Other question, where I can store Roles that are returned from API on login? Because I need them for deciding which route to open for which user. If I store it in `Local Storage` I have same problem (injecting roles), I think.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you get a Token when logging in, in response, and store it in Storage (In my opinion you should use Session Storage), if you enter invalid token you will get an error on any api call, just handle the error to empty the storage and navigate you back to login or whatever

Comment: I will add that for clearing token in Api calls. But explain me about Session Storage, it is present until browser/tab is closed. How thanI keep user logged in when he return to the website?

Comment: @ElementW If you use local storage, you have to empty it manually (i think), session storage works until you close the tab (which is good)